# Почему компилятор может оптимизировать сравнение при доступе за границы массива?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, неопределённое-поведение

```
bool contains(int val) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i) 
        if (arr[i] == val) 
            return true; 
            
    return false;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {    
    std::cout << contains(2);
    std::cout << contains(4);
}
```

Почему с оптимизацией `-O2` компилятор может превратить функцию в [возврат единицы](https://godbolt.org/z/hj5PGh)?

Понятно, что тут неопределённое поведение, но непонятно, почему оно позволяет так оптимизировать код, что результат в итоге неверный.

Comment: неопределённое поведение позволяет делать что угодно...

Comment: @user7860670 формально да, но по какой логике детерминированный компилятор так делает? Например, `x+1>x` для знаковых целых понятно, почему можно соптимизировать в единицу, а тут не очень

Comment: неопределённое поведение позволяет детерминированному компилятору выдавать какой угодно результат.

Comment: ну не просто какой угодно, а тот, который ему удобный в данный момент для оптимизации..

Comment: Наверное, он посчитал для 2, и решил, что этот результат надо выдать и для 4 :)

Comment: Если код анализировал бы человек, а не программа(компилятор), то вполне мог бы думать так:  "ну раз обрабатываются 4  элемента, а в массиве 1, 2 и 3, скорее написавший код хотел  еще и четверку добавить в список инициализации, но забыл. Давай верну ему истину на всякий случай..."  Компилятор тоже может так  вести себя _ он написан людьми.  Как хочет, так и "подумает"

Comment: После того как цикл будет развернут, в дереве ветвлений увидим 4 ветки: 3 ветки заканчиваются `return true`, а четвертая - неопределенным поведением. Компилятор вправе предположить что ветка с неопределенным поведением - недостижима.

Comment: @Chorkov если бы там был только `return true`, то я согласен. Но там же в конце есть `return false` ещё, почему он не учитывается?

Comment: @gauss возврат false возможен только после того как будет выполнено сравнение `arr[4] == val` - которое содержит неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @Chorkov то есть когда мы встретили неопределённое поведение, которое для компилятора как бы не существует (поэтому можно выбросить проверку в `x+1>x`), всё что дальше можно отбрасывать, а не только саму ветку с неопределённым поведением? То есть почему он выкидывает не только `arr[4] == val`, но и следующий `return false`?

Comment: @gauss Да. Всю ветку приведшею к неопределенному поведению можно отбросить.

Comment: @Chorkov согласен, типа может быть false, только если было сравнение `arr[4] == val`, но его не могло быть, потому что было бы неопределённое поведение. Можете дать ответ - приму

Answer (score 5):

Преобразование допустимо, потому что стандарт не определяет поведение программы в этом случае, а значит может быть всё что угодно.

По какой логике компилятор мог преобразовать вызов функции в `return true;`?

Потому что исполнение `return false;` может произойти, только если `arr[3] == val` стало `false`, но с точки зрения компилятора программист предоставляет гарантию об отсутствии неопределённого поведения, а значит доступа `arr[3]` не может произойти. Раз не может произойти доступа `arr[3]`, то и `arr[3] == val` не может стать `false`. Так как все оставшиеся пути выполнения функции возвращают `true`, можно соптимизировать её до чистого `return true;`.

Кстати, *gcc* в этом смысле более агрессивен; *clang* возвращает значение, в зависимости от того, меньше ли переданный аргумент минус единица тройки, получая ожидаемый результат ([сравнение](https://godbolt.org/z/vqaE45)). С -O1 результаты верные у обоих компиляторов.

---

<sup>Использовались комментарии участников [@user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670), [@Chorkov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186057/chorkov), [@gauss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/407006/gauss).</sup>